# How to approximate the Langford numbers with probability?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

A Langford pairing, also called a Langford sequence is a permutation of the multi set {$1,1,2,2, \dots, n,n$} in such a way that there are exactly $k$ elements in between every $k$.

Interestingly, such an arrangement is only possible when $n \equiv -1,0 \pmod 4$. The number of different pairings for a given value of $n$ is given by $L_n$.

Note the use of the word different. A permutation is said to be different from another permutation, if one cannot be gotten from the other by reversing the order. So, $L_3 = L_4 = 1$. The permutation for $n = 3$ is $312132$. It's reverse permutation $231213$ is not considered different so the value of $L_n = 1$.

Now, for the question. 
If a permutation of ${1,1,2,2, \dots n,n}$ is chosen at random, what is the probability that two $k$'s are exactly $k$ positions apart, given $k$ ? Use this to guess the size of Langford numbers $L_{n}$.

I have been able to make neither head nor tail of the solution given in the book.

$2n - k - 1$ of the $\binom{2n}{2}$ equally likely pairs of positions satisfy the stated condition. If these probabilities were independent, (they aren't) the value of $2L_n$ would be

$$
\begin{align}
\binom{2n}{2,2,2, \dots 2}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2n - k - 1}{\binom{2n}{2}} &= \frac{(2n)!^2n(n-1)}{n!(2n)^{n+1}(2n -1)^{n+1}} \\
&=\exp(n\ln\frac{4n}{e^3} +\ln\sqrt \frac{\pi e n}{2} + O(n^{-1}))\\
\end{align}
$$

I understand why there are $\binom{2n}{2}$ pairs in total but why are $2n - k - 1$ pairs chosen out ? How is that number picked out ? 
Placing two elements $k$ positions apart is equivalent to choosing a contiguous string $k + 2$ length. So, there should be $2n - k - 2$.But, it is not. What is the reason for this ?

Independent probability of what ? How does that imply the value of $2L_{n}$ ? And why is that expression a product of a multi nominal coefficient and a product ?

I could understand the first equality but have no clue about the final equality. I'm not sure how the factor of $O(n^{-1})$ comes up. Here's the formula that I think will help.

$$\ln n! = n\ln n - n + O(\ln n)$$

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: What does "Langford number" mean please?

Comment: @NP-hard Dear friend, I have updated the question.

Comment: Why did you change the title? The original one was a lot more specific.

Comment: @joriki Because I think that the specificity was scaring off a lot of people in thinking that background knowledge is required. Since, I've defined everything from scratch, they don't need any perquisite knowledge and don't need to be scared off.

Comment: If something was scaring people off, it wasn't the specificity but the unfamiliar term "Langford pair". I've made the title more specific, in familiar terms. A title like "probability question in permutations" is useless; the word "question" in the title of a question on a question & answer site is a waste of space, and "probability" and "permutations" are already in the tags. We get lots of questions with such careless titles, and they're usually much less interesting than yours; I think such a title scares off more of the people who might be able to answer your question than "Langford pair".

Comment: @joriki I changed the title again. The previous two titles seemed too ... bureaucratic for me to say. I've made it sound less cluttered. Since my question is more or less answered, I'm not looking for another answer. Although some things are still unclear.

Comment: If some things are still unclear, do feel free to ask.

Comment: @joriki The only problem is the algebra from the second last to final step. In particular, that $O(n^{-1})$ !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the $2n-k-1$ pairs, you're miscounting by $1$. You're right that a string of length $k+2$ is being placed, but there are $m-j+1$ positions for a string of length $j$ in $m$ elements, not $m-j$. (This is perhaps easiest to see for $m=j$.)

Independent probability of what? Of each pair being placed at the right distance. The first multinomial factor counts the permutations of the elements, and the product multiplies the probabilities for each pair to be at the right distance. If these probabilities were independent (which they aren't), multiplying them would yield the probability that all pairs are at the right distance simultaneously, and multiplying that by the total number of equiprobable permutations would then yield the number of admissible permutations.

The number of permutations is given by that multinomial coefficient because there are $2n$ elements to permute, but each pair can be permuted among themselves without changing the permutation, so $n$ factors of $2!$ need to be divided out of $(2n)!$.

The factor $2$ in $2L_n$ is to account for the fact that $L_n$ only counts the permutations up to reflection.

For the final equality, use

$$
n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac n{\mathrm e}\right)^n\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)
$$

(see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Derivation)). Then

\begin{align}
\frac{(2n)!^2n(n-1)}{n!(2n)^{n+1}(2n -1)^{n+1}}
&=\frac{2\pi2n\left(\frac{2n}{\mathrm e}\right)^{4n}\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)n(n-1)}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac n{\mathrm e}\right)^n\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)(2n)^{n+1}(2n-1)^{n+1}}
\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi n/2}n^n2^{2n}\left(1-\frac1n\right)}{\mathrm e^{3n}\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)^{n+1}}\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)
\\
&=
\frac{\sqrt{\pi\mathrm e n/2}n^n2^{2n}}{\mathrm e^{3n}}\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\;,
\end{align}

and taking the logarithm yields the quoted result. (Here $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n=\mathrm e^x\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)$ was used.)

Comment: I have put up a detailed exposition.

Comment: @user230452: OK, I've put up a more detailed answer. In view of the unexpected factor $2$ in the $L_n$ (from order reversal), the original question should definitely have contained a definition of these numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm feeling happy as I'm beginning to understand it. Can I ask how you understood the question and got the answer so quickly ? What's your mathematical background ?

Comment: @user230452: It's often hard to explain how one understands and solves problems. In the present case, I think it was just a lot of experience with combinatorics and probability -- for instance, the fact that the expected number of things with a property is the product of the total number of things times the probability for the property to hold becomes obvious over time. My background is in theoretical physics; I actually only developed an interest in probability and combinatorics while hanging around this site for the last couple of years :-)

Comment: So, are you a professor or something ? I'm pretty bad at Physics. Lol. What are some books that have been influential on you ?

Comment: @user230452: No, I'm not a professor, I'm in politics now. It's been a long time since books influenced me; the first that comes to mind is Quantum Mechanics by Cohen-Tannoudji. Much more influential for me than any book has been this site (and of course Wikipedia).

Comment: Politics ? That's surprising.

Comment: The Wikipedia page for Stirling's expansion explained where the $O(n^{-1})$ term comes from. So, I'll probably understand the whole thing within half an hour. I'm going to accept your answer and then upload my own solution to go over all the steps that are glazed over in the book.

Comment: I have put in the formula that I think will help. Can you try it now ? Still don't know how to introduce $\pi$, $\e$ and get $O(n^{-1}$ from $O(\ln n)$. I don't know how to manipulate the Big-O function.

Comment: @user230452: I've added that calculation to the answer.

Comment: It's pretty brilliant. I must say. Good job !

Comment: What happened to the two terms that disappeared in between the second and third step ?

Comment: Also, won't there be a factor of $n^2n$ in the denominator ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41651/discussion-between-joriki-and-user230452).

Comment: Sorry. I'm not able to post in chat, but I read your message. You can answer these questions in chat. Why is the $1 + O(n^{-1}$ term there in the second step ? Doesn't it get cancelled both in the numerator and denominator. Secondly, won't the numerator then have the term $e^{-1}$ by the formula provided in the parenthesis ?

Comment: Yes, I do mean $n^{2n}$.

Comment: I don't see why you think there should be a factor $n^{2n}$; all the factors of $n$ are accounted for. There are $1+4n+2=4n+3$ in the numerator and $\frac12+n+n+1+n+1=3n+\frac52$ in the denominator, so $(4n+3)-(3n+\frac52)=n+\frac12$ left in the numerator.

Comment: Ah ... I see now. Didn't see the $4$ clearly.

Comment: About canceling $1+O\left(\frac1n\right)$: You can't cancel that. You may be confused by the slightly sloppy notation we use in this regard. $O\left(\frac1n\right)$ isn't a specific function; it's a set of functions, like an error bar. Just like you can't say $(1\pm0.1)-(1\pm0.1)=0\pm0.0$, you can't say $O\left(\frac1n\right)-O\left(\frac1n\right)=0$ or $O\left(\frac1n\right)/O\left(\frac1n\right)=1$.

Comment: Lastly is $ln(1 + O(\frac1n) )= O(\frac1n)$ ?

Comment: @user230452: Yes, from the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$.

Comment: @user230452: So e.g. $\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)= 1+O\left(\frac1n\right)$ and also $\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)/ \left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)=1+O\left(\frac1n\right)$ (using the Taylor series for $1/(1+x)$).

Comment: Wow. So, the error factor comes once in the numerator and once in the denominator again (in the step where $e^{-\frac12}$ comes up), right ? We don't have to account for that ?

Comment: @user230452: No, see my last comment (posted two seconds before yours :-). Any product or quotient of factors of $1+O\left(\frac1n\right)$ yields only a factor $1+O\left(\frac1n\right)$ together.

Comment: Wow. I finally understood everything. Thanks for answering all my questions.

Comment: I'm just a bit worried about how I'll ever finish the book of it took me one full day to work though just one !

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't have much experience with such approximations, perhaps try them out with some concrete small examples, e.g. convince yourself that $\mathrm e^x=1+O(x)$ and $\mathrm e^{2x}=\mathrm e^x\mathrm e^x=(1+O(x))(1+O(x))=1+O(x)$.

Comment: Is it something like $f(x) + g(x) = h(x)$ and all three functions are represented by the same class ?

Comment: @user230452: Yes. $O(x)$ is the class of functions that are bounded in magnitude by some constant times $x$. Adding or subtracting two such functions again yields a function in that class.

Comment: Yes, but not multiplication and division ! It changes the degree.

Comment: @user230452: $O(x)\cdot O(x)=O(x^2)$, but $(1+O(x))(1+O(x))=1+O(x)+O(x)+O(x)\cdot O(x)= 1+O(x)+O(x^2)=1+O(x)$. This notation is always relative to a certain limit; here it's $x\to0$, so $O(x^2)$ is a subset of $O(x)$. In your case the limit is $n\to\infty$, and then $O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$ is a subset of $O\left(\frac1n\right)$.

Comment: $1 - \frac1n = e^{-1}(1+O(\frac1n)$, right ? So that $e$ should come in the denominator of the square root. Or did I miss something in between

Comment: @user230452: $\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)^{n+1}\to\mathrm e^{-1/2}$ in the denominator; so we need to put the reciprocal of $\mathrm e^{-1/2}$ in the numerator, i.e. $\mathrm e^{1/2}$.